# javascript fetch vs jquery .post issue -- fetch only works inside of source domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fetch

I have a fetch query and an jquery .post query:

```
fetch('https://example.com/myAPI.asp', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({r: `gift_cards`, email: `bobo@example.com`, gcHash: `2bf2920a12d3063df4812a9437f2ce99`})
  }).then(res=>res.json()).then(data=>{
    console.log(data);
  });
  

$.post('https://example.com/myAPI.asp',{r: `gift_cards`, email: `bobo@example.com`, gcHash: `2bf2920a12d3063df4812a9437f2ce99`})
.then(data => {
    data=JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data);
});
```

Both work if I'm within example.com. However, the fetch function does not work outside of example.com. I do not get an error but the promise is fulfilled with "[[PromiseResult]]: undefined",

The ajax function always works from whichever site it's called from. It's not a cors issue, therefore. How do I fix my fetch query?

Comment: It's possible to POST to a different domain. What CORS does is make it impossible for you to get the *results* from that HTTP request. There is almost certainly no difference between your two examples. You should use the browser Network developer tool to look at the actual request/response details.

Comment: If it were a cors issue, the jquery post would not work.

Comment: Like I said, use the Network console to examine *exactly* what's going on.

Comment: Also, how are you so confident that CORS is not part of the issue here? Do you know that "example.com" has CORS headers that allow access from any other domain?

Comment: Yes. It's not a CORS issue. The network console reveals nothing untowards except that the .post returns parsable data and the fetch does not.

Comment: Well what *does* the `fetch()` return? Anything? Are there differences between the HTTP request headers?